# #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql

Hi so I'm attempting to get all books in a series that a customer hasn't ordered yet. My current theory is that the best way to do this was to find what book series they have ordered. then build a list of all the books in those series and then find all the books in that list that they haven't ordered. However in my attempts to word a messy triple query I get the above error after only getting to the second part. Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT books.bookid
FROM books, bookseries, series
WHERE books.bookID=bookseries.bookID 
      AND bookseries.bookID=series.seriesID
      series.seriesID IN (SELECT series.seriesID, COUNT(series.seriesID) as cnt
                          FROM customers, orders, orderlines, books, bookseries, series
                          WHERE customers.custID=1
                                AND customers.custID=orders.custID
                                AND orders.orderID=orderlines.orderID
                                AND orderlines.bookID=books.bookID
                                AND books.bookID=bookseries.bookID
                                AND bookseries.seriesID=series.seriesID
                          GROUP BY series.seriesID
                          ORDER BY cnt desc LIMIT 1)
```

I know for a fact that inside query works; only it returns two columns, seriesID and cnt and I think that might be my problem but I'm not sure. I also saw that a lot of people have had this issue and joins usually work but I don't quite know enough about them. Can someone help/teach me? Perhaps suggest a better way? Speed isn't too important, this is to test some things out on a fun project I'm working on. Thank you very much!

Ok let me know if I'm doing this wrong but: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6816c/1 is what the database looks like. I'm trying to get an output of book titles that are in the same series that I know a customer likes and that they don't own. So for user 1 I know they have harry potter 1, 2, 6, 7. So my query will find that they like the harry potter series and output the titles they don' t own which in this case is Harry Potter 3, 4, 5. Or Azkaban, Goblet of Fire and order of the phoenix.

In summary: Step one: find all the series that customer has books from. Step two: Find all the books from all those series. Step three: find the books in that list that the customer doesn't own.

Comment: It would be great if you could share the structure of those three tables.

Comment: Sorry about that it is here: https://imgur.com/FvoZEI7

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you  haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry I added it in. hex494D49 I added some additional info as to what I'm looking for. It's really close though so thank you!

Comment: Any feedback :) Have you found the answer below useful?

Comment: Yes it was very useful! I ended up using your code with first half of mine as posted below for the complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching books of the series (1) that aren't yet ordered by customer (1)

```
SELECT b.bookID, b.title
FROM books AS b
INNER JOIN bookseries AS bs ON bs.bookID = b.bookID AND bs.seriesID = 1
WHERE b.bookID NOT IN (
  SELECT ol.bookID
  FROM orders AS o
  INNER JOIN orderlines AS ol ON ol.orderID = o.orderID
  INNER JOIN books AS b ON b.bookID = ol.bookID
  WHERE o.custID = 1
)
```

Or

```
SELECT b.bookID, b.title
FROM books AS b
INNER JOIN bookseries AS bs ON bs.bookID = b.bookID AND bs.seriesID = 1 
LEFT JOIN orderlines AS ol ON ol.bookID = b.bookID
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.orderID = ol.orderID AND o.custID = 1
WHERE ol.bookID IS NULL
```

Usage in PHP:

```
$rs = mysqli_query("SELECT b.bookID, b.title
FROM books AS b
INNER JOIN bookseries AS bs ON bs.bookID = b.bookID AND bs.seriesID = " . $_GET["seriesID"] . "
WHERE b.bookID NOT IN (
  SELECT ol.bookID
  FROM orders AS o
  INNER JOIN orderlines AS ol ON ol.orderID = o.orderID
  INNER JOIN books AS b ON b.bookID = ol.bookID
  WHERE o.custID = " . $_GET["custID"] . "
)");

while($b = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $b["bookID"] . " - " . $b["title"] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Close to what I'm looking for! I don't want ALL the books, I just want all the books in that series. I added a link to a sqlfiddle if that helps. Meanwhile I'll try to understand how your query works

Comment: Yes exactly what I want but instead of "bs.seriesID = 1" the seriesID needs to come from a query. Which is the part I've been having trouble with. Getting the query part to work with the first one.

Comment: OK. My head hurts ;-)

Comment: Step one: find all the series that customer has books from. Step two: Find all the books from all those series. Step three: find the books in that list that the customer doesn't own.

Comment: @Patman Just replace `... AND bs.seriesID = 1` with `... AND bs.seriesID = " . $_GET["id"] . "`

Comment: @hex494D49 No. The series comes from the query!

Comment: @Strawberry Actually I run this test online so I guess thy have an older version, 'cause my first attempt was using RIGHT JOIN which is just normal in this situation

Comment: How does right join work? Can you craft it on that sql fiddle?

Comment: @hex494D49 Sorry, you've lost me. I doubt that there was ever a version of MySQL that didn't support RIGHT JOIN - but please prove me wrong!

Comment: @hex494D49 In my original question the second half the query (the part in the parenthesis) works and finds the top series, just remove the limit part. Can you use that someway?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, I'm lost as well :) Let me explain it, when I saw the structure provided by OP in .jpg I recognized that it is very similar to a standard Microsoft database provided with Access and SQL Server... and I wanted to find it somewhere online 'cause I was lazy to code all the tables above in SQL Fiddle :) This is the link (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) It might be Access in a background but I was focused on the query itself and not on the engine in the background :)

Comment: @Patman Give me a couple of minutes please. Honestly, I found your query quite long for this purpose and that's why I didn't take it into account :) Let me analyze it now...

Comment: @Patman Check the updated answer; I added another query to do the same job. And please don't get me wrong but I just can't make your query work... somehow I can't understand what you were trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.bookID, b.title
FROM books AS b
INNER JOIN bookseries AS bs ON bs.bookID = b.bookID AND bs.seriesID IN (
  SELECT series.seriesID
  FROM customers, orders, orderlines, books, bookseries, series
  WHERE customers.custID=1
        AND customers.custID=orders.custID
        AND orders.orderID=orderlines.orderID
        AND orderlines.bookID=books.bookID
        AND books.bookID=bookseries.bookID
        AND bookseries.seriesID=series.seriesID
  GROUP BY series.seriesID)
WHERE b.bookID NOT IN (
  SELECT ol.bookID
  FROM orders AS o
  INNER JOIN orderlines AS ol ON ol.orderID = o.orderID
  INNER JOIN books AS b ON b.bookID = ol.bookID
  WHERE o.custID = 1
)
```

Okay the format is a little weird but this is my final query. Big thanks to @hex494D49 for getting me on the right track!

Comment: +1 for being kind, thankful and for mixing all together LOL I'm looking at this huge query as a transition phase and in hope that you'll make it more compact in the next stage ;)

Comment: ...of course! It's just a fun project I'm not too worried how ugly it is.